# python errorUnicodeDecodeError query

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read content of all the files from a root directory. Here is my code for it:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('akira'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.txt'):
     with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as f:
        f.read()
```

While compiling the file it is giving me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 88: invalid start byte.
```

I am not able to fix this error. I need suggestions to solve it.

Comment: You have files that don't use UTF-8. What are you using the data *for*, do you need to read the binary data or do you need the text? What kinds of files do you have? You need to specify an encoding if you want text data, but if the text files are inconsistently encoded that can get tricky.

Comment: What is happening is that `open()` opens files in text mode by default and uses the default encoding for your system to do so; in this case that's UTF-8.

Comment: i need to read all the text,the files contain all the special characters too

Comment: Yes, but you need to then use the correct encoding. `open(..., encoding='<codec_for_the_file>')`. Do you know what codec is the correct one? Do all files use that codec?

Comment: I got the solution.I put encoding='latin1' and it is working fine now

Comment: Be careful! Latin-1 works for **any** file but is not necessarily the right codec. Watch out for 'strange' characters in the output.